# Python 3 - ttk.treeview does not working with grid, why this happening?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Gentleman's

the following code have been working with `.pack()` but does not working with `.grid()`

the `treeview` has Scrollbar working when `.pack()` is enabled but if I change the code for `.grid()` the Scrollbar stop to working, there is some possibility the code working with `.grid()`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter  import ttk

class App(object):
    def run(self):
        root=Tk()
        root.geometry('768x612')
        title='dp'
        root.title(title)
        head_columns = (
            "ID CLIENTE", 
            "NOME", 
            "CPF", 
            "DATA Expedição CPF", 
            "RG", 
            "DATA Expedição RG", 
            "ENDEREÇO", 
            "NÚMERO", 
            "BAIRRO", "CIDADE", "ESTADO", "CEP", "TEL", "CEL", "E-MAIL", "OBS")        

        f = Frame(root)
        f.pack()
        #f.grid()

        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(f, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='both')

        text = ttk.Treeview(f,
                    xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                    show="headings", 
                    columns=head_columns,)
        text.pack(side='right', fill='y') #if I change this for .grid() he's not working

        for item in text["columns"]:
            text.column(item)
            text.heading(item, text=item)
        text.insert("", 0, text=item, values=("a" * 200))

        xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
        mainloop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    win=App()
    win.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I already solved my problem,

The `.grid()` too working with Scrollbar but if you fixed width and height with `.geometry()` in your window they don't will scroll and so I did need set my window resize with followings parameters, basically you need to do your window resize auto for scroll work

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Well done for solving this yourself. For future reference, it is good practise to always configure at least one row and one column to have a weight when using grid to create your GUI :)

Comment: Yeap, Thanks man! I to do this with another function that I created

Answer (score -1):

FIY

CODE SOLVED

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter  import ttk

class App(object):
    def run(self):
        root=Tk()
        #root.geometry('768x612')
        title='Tables'
        root.title(title)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        head_columns = (
            "ID CLIENTE", 
            "NOME", 
            "CPF", 
            "DATA Expedição CPF", 
            "RG", 
            "DATA Expedição RG", 
            "ENDEREÇO", 
            "NÚMERO", 
            "BAIRRO", "CIDADE", "ESTADO", "CEP", "TEL", "CEL", "E-MAIL", "OBS")        

        f = Frame(root)
        f.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        f.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        f.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(f, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.grid(row=1, sticky=NSEW)
        xscrollbar.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        xscrollbar.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        text = ttk.Treeview(f,
                    xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                    show="headings", 
                    columns=head_columns)
        #text.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        text.grid(row=0,sticky=NSEW)
        text.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        text.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        for item in text["columns"]:
            text.column(item)
            text.heading(item, text=item)
        text.insert("", 0, text=item, values=("a" * 200))
        text.insert("", 1, text=item, values=("a" * 200))
        text.insert("", 0, text=item, values=("a" * 200))
        text.insert("", 0, text=item, values=("a" * 200))
        text.insert("", 0, text=item, values=("a" * 200))
        text.insert("", 0, text=item, values=("a" * 200))

        xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
        mainloop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    win=App()
    win.run()
```